# Where to find last x hour/minute trading volume for a given coin

Tags: trading, volume, altcoin

Coinmarketcap shows trading volume for the last 24 hour. Where can I find trading volume for the last x hour/minute? Or How can I calculate it myself programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com) has the utility you need.

1. Go to `Coins` at the top, find your coin
2. Analysis
3. Change the bar graph at the bottom to display by Hour
4. Use the interface to see the volume per second

If this is too unwieldy, cryptocompare does have an api and a useful [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptocompare) to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest way to do this yourself would be to read the API docs of each exchange and write your own code for downloading minutely price data and that will also include volume data. You can then resample later according your needs.

For example,

- https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs
- https://docs.gdax.com/